# Sending Email with a generated ID in Subject

Tags: javascript, random, mailto

So here is the link of the fiddle. I already tried a lots of searches and tried combining codes from other sites but cant seem to figure out the error.
https://jsfiddle.net/itsmrchadd/fqjhu03r/2/

Based on the subject i just need pop up outlook with the ID in it. Sorry im a bit beginner here. :)

The random generator is already working i was able to test that separately. The only problem is the sending of email. If you try to click the link nothing happens, it would just load for a couple of seconds then stops.

```js
function generateEmailID(length, chars) {
 "use strict";
 
 //Set default values
 var result = '';
 var timestamp = +new Date().toString(36).slice(2);
    
 //Set optional values
 length = length || 7;
 chars = chars || '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
 
 //Generate the id based on the parameters with timestamp
   for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) {
  result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
 }
 return timestamp + result;
}

function sendEmail(email, subject, body) {
 "use strict";
 
 //Set optional values
   email = email || "random@random.random";
 subject = subject + " [" + generateEmailID() + "]" || "Test [" + generateEmailID() + "]";
   body = body || "Test";
  
   //Send email with id generated in the subject
 window.location.href = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="sendEmail()">Send Email</a>
```

Comment: In JS, one-line comments start with `//`, not `'`, so the code as shown in the question and in the fiddle wouldn't run at all.

Comment: @nnnnnn - i just edited the code.... and the fiddle link... but still its just refreshing/doing nothing

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle update the javascript settings and for the **LOAD TYPE** choose one of the last two options:

[image]

It worked for me.

Comment: but when i add the reference link to the head of my html... it would just refresh

Comment: <script src="assets/javascript/sendemail.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1):

The Fiddle doesn't work because somehow the link is being created before the js is created (but here in stackoverflow's "Run code snippet" your code does work).

(In JSFiddle hit F12 to see the console log in the browser for the error.)

To fix it in the JSFiddle you can refer to the function before creating the element as follows:

html:

```
<script>var sendEmail();</script>
<a href="#" onclick="sendEmail()">Send Email</a>
```

with your js having a small change:

```
sendEmail = function(email, subject, body) {
//(...rest of code stays the same)
```

or when you create it in a html page, just put the js in the `head`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        //(...js here)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- html link here -->
    <a href="#" onclick="sendEmail()">Send Email</a>
</body>
</html>
```

...thus, the code would be as follows: (I added a few other changes, such as for code that didn't seem necessary ie `.slice(2)` and setting `subject = ''` when it is undefined...)

```js
function generateEmailID(length, chars) {
 //"use strict";
 
 //Set default values
 var result = '';
 var timestamp = new Date().toString(36); //.slice(2);
    //console.log(timestamp);
    
 //Set optional values
 length = length || 7;
 chars = chars || '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
 
 //Generate the id based on the parameters with timestamp
  for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) {
  result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
 }
    //console.log(timestamp + result);
 return timestamp + result;
}

sendEmail = function(email, subject, body) {
 //"use strict";
    if(!subject) subject = '';
 
 //Set optional values
    email = email || "random@random.random";
 subject = subject + " [" + generateEmailID() + "]" || "Test [" + generateEmailID() + "]";
    body = body || "Test";
    
    //Send email with id generated in the subject
    window.location.href = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="sendEmail()">Send Email</a>
```

Comment: I see Amir gave the easiset answer that you can change where the javascript is loaded from in JSFiddle... to "in head"... well done Amir...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help. i already got what i wanted.....
its also now working fine together with my htmls

here is the link of the final fiddle....
https://jsfiddle.net/itsmrchadd/fqjhu03r/3/

```js
function generateEmailID(length, chars) {
 "use strict";
 
 //Set default values
 var result = '';
 var timestamp = +new Date().toString(36).slice(2);
    
 //Set optional values
 length = length || 7;
 chars = chars || '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
 
 //Generate the id based on the parameters with timestamp
   for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) {
  result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
 }
  return timestamp + result;
  
  
}

function sendEmail(email, subject, body) {
 "use strict";
 
  //Set default values
  if (!subject) {
  subject = "Test";
 }
  
 //Set optional values
   email = email || "random@random.random";
  subject = subject + " [" + generateEmailID() + "]" || "Test";
   body = body || "Test";
  
   //Send email with id generated in the subject
 window.location.href = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="sendEmail()">Send Email</a>
```